# go to url in javascript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to go to external url from my website with this code

```js
var embed = "www.youtube.com";  
console.log(embed);
window.location.assign(embed);
```

However, the webpage doesn't go to the the link in var embed but go instead to 
Mywebsite/thepageofthatcode/www.youtube.com

```js
window.location = "www.youtube.com";
window.location.href = "www.youtube.com";
```

I didn't get why is this happening?

Comment: "www.youtube.com" is not a URL

Comment: There are lots of answers that answer your question. Please mark one of them as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure you add the http for external websites:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
```

Comment: thanks, I feel so stupid right now...

Answer (score 1):

Add the protocol to make it work. Without the protocol it will search for www.youtube.com under your domain which is why it is redirecting to that way. Try

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com';
```

Comment: thanks, I feel so stupid right now...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the protocol before the url. Otherwise, the browser will think that it is a path.

```js
var embed = "http://www.youtube.com";  
console.log(embed);
window.location.assign(embed);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Add the protocol to make it work. Without the protocol, it thinks that www.youtube.com is a part of your website.

This is the problem. But here's a better why to fix it:

```
// Use RegExp to test if embed already has the protocol
// If not, prepend it to embed.
if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(embed))
    embed = 'http://' + embed;

window.location.href = embed;
```

[RegExp guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

[URL Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem, only need to add the `http` part to the url

```
var embed = "http://www.youtube.com";  
window.open(embed);
```